# Using linked list to solve hash conflicts, what's the next step to identify the item

Tags: algorithm, hash, linked-list, theory

I'm using a very simple hash algorithm that map a string to an 32bit int, suppose the hash is bad, that both stringB and stringA got number 123, now should I traverse the linked list, try to compare all items with the item I'm looking for, until I find the right one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a linked list per bucket is one way to do it: if the item is in the list, you are done; otherwise, add a new item at the end of the list.

The other is to try the next bucket in the table in a loop, until you find an empty one.

Comment: A third way is to have a different-sized hash table (although that is only useful if the hash equivalence is due to an unfortunate modulus).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your hashing strategy is based on closed hashing with LinkedList and that your linled list ordering is based on order of insertion, I would traverse items and compare them on the content, maybe with `if ( string1.compareTo(string2) == 0 ){ ...` if you want to keep `equals()` for hashing.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. You could also refer this site http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions (Apart from Wiki,ofcourse!)

There can be different variations for searching elements mapped to a particular bucket- You could have multi-level hashtables,or even a Binary Search Tree, not just a linked list!

Answer (score 0):

To handle hash conflicts, a suitable approach would be to re-hash the conflicting (subsequent) values. It's hard to estimate run-time behavior of the original hash function, which means that the occurrence of conflicts is unknown. Hashing conflicting values using another hash function and storing them in a second-level table will still be an optimal time look-up overall.